# Dual Delphi IDEs

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, desktop

I use two monitors on my development system and I would like to run Delphi XE2 on both left and right. This seems to work alright and allows me to develop a client on one side and matching server on the other.
The only problem is that the IDEs seem to get confused on which monitor to start on in both design and Run time.

I have a Desktop Speed setting for left and right and I have two completly separate projects setup. Is there a setting I have missed?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is, and what question you ask

Comment: I've been considering getting a 4k monitor so I can have multiple instances of the IDE running on the SAME monitor. But I'm not sure this will result in better behavior. You just have to open stuff then move it where you want it. The IDE has no way of managing this. But your run-time windows could implement their own screen-placement save/restore logic.

Comment: I have two monitors too, and I often have the same problem. The window on the secondary screen sometimes comes up on the main screen, as it seem to forget what monitor it was on. I found that if I do not maximize the window then it happens less often.

Comment: From the keyboard, Win+Shift+left/right arrow key gets the job done. That's probably all you need.

Answer (score 4):

When you run an application in the IDE, the IDE switches to what is by default named as `Debug Layout` in the IDE layout dropdown. You can setup and save different debug layouts and then activate the one(s) you want after you started the applications. E.g. `Debug in Left Monitor` and `Debug in Right Monitor`.

**Edit**

However, for a layout to switch to the monitor it was setup on, it (the layout) can not be maximized.

Comment: Yes Tom that is exactly what I wanted. Now I can have two IDEs open that stay on there own side of the fence when I run their app.

Comment: @SetiNet I don't think such multi-monitor multi-IDE support was ever considered by Embarcadero. I think this is the answer to your question, and your underlying problem doesn't have a solution due to lack of feature support.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in the IDE, a shortcut to the IDE, or a specific project, to specify which monitor the IDE/project starts on. If your app wants to start on a particular monitor at runtime, its own code has to manage that at startup ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208266/how-do-you-control-what-monitor-your-application-opens-on)). Otherwise, it is at the mercy of the OS deciding monitor to start it on.

Comment: I try again to explain it.
I have two monitors. I can open an IDE on both of them. Which one goes where is set by the Desktop Speedsetting drop down on each of the IDEs.

 If I hit run from the left IDE the app opens over the top of the IDE - Good.

If I hit run from the right IDE the app opens but the IDE slides over on top of the left IDE - not good. I would like it to stay on the left.

Comment: Again, unless your app FORCES that behavior, Windows decides which monitor to use, not the IDE.  It sounds like your left monitor is the primary monitor, and Windows is choosing to show the app on the primary monitor.  Which makes sense.