# Batch script to start applications on specific screen

Tags: batch-file, windows-8, startup, multiscreen

What I want is have my programs that open on startup, to popup on specified desktop screens. For example: my Email Client and browser on the right screen and my Notepad++ application on the left screen.

Is it possible to do this with batch script?

Comment: This may help you write a script to change default screen locations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755/what-determines-the-monitor-my-app-runs-on